# why my str_replace cannot use in \ symbol in php

Tags: php, str-replace

```php
$originalMessage = "hello i want to \ this pc";
$replaceMessage = str_replace('\', 'check', $originalMessage );
```

And system show the error below:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" ,"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace('\', 'check', $originalMessage );
```

The `'\'` part [escapes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) the closing `'`, therefore PHP is still waiting for the string closure.

This can be seen clearly in a nice IDE:
[image]

---

Would recommend escaping the `\` to prevent it from escaping the `'`.

```
str_replace('\\', 'check', $originalMessage );
```

which you can test [on this online demo](https://tio.run/##ZYzBCsIwEAXv@xWPUoiC@ANRPAkeFPsBgRLC0g2GZkkCfn70IAh6G4ZhVLT3w0lFicZc4hJXn25cq18YRwzCKWVEPP3a0DIcmsQKDYOlsbAmH/ib11bmj9wY58wOJgiHxxv@5ltLxEEyfjd7TJdpPt@vtvcX)!

Comment: but my symbol "\" also not change to "check"

when i using this 
str_replace('\\', 'check', $originalMessage );

Comment: It seems to [be working fine](https://tio.run/##ZYzBCsIwEAXv@xWPUoiC@ANRPAkeFPsBgRLC0g2GZkkCfn70IAh6G4ZhVLT3w0lFicZc4hJXn25cq18YRwzCKWVEPP3a0DIcmsQKDYOlsbAmH/ib11bmj9wY58wOJgiHxxv@5ltLxEEyfjd7TJdpPt@vtvcX "PHP – Try It Online")